# При программном добавлении View выходят за пределы экрана

Tags: android, android-layout

Добавляю в `Layout` программно большое количество кнопок и они формируются в одну строку и вылазят за пределы видимости справа.
Как сделать, чтобы они автоматически формировались со следующей строчки если по ширине уже не влазят? Спасибо.

```
   protected void drawVariant(){
        /*Создаем вложенный Макет*/
        linearLayoutInner = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayoutInner.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsInner = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParamsInner.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        /*Создаем вложеный кнопки*/
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int countId = 0;
        for (String x : array) {
            Button tvLater = new Button(this);
            tvLater.setOnClickListener(this);
            tvLater.setText("|"+x+"|");
            linearLayoutInner.addView(tvLater,textViewParams);
            tvLater.setId(++countId);
            id.add(countId);

        }
        linearLayoutMain.addView(linearLayoutInner, layoutParamsInner);
    }
```

Comment: Как минимум не использовать LinearLayout.

Comment: Может еще кто-то подскажет обязательно ли задавать id элементам чтобы потом можно было их обработать через OnClickListener или можно как по другому?

Comment: Если вы сами создаете вьюхи то нет. Достаточно добавить следующий код: tvLayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
   {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v)
    {
     
    }
   });

Comment: Хм. Действительно. Спасибо.

Comment: А можно подробней про "Как минимум не использовать LinearLayout." Что вы предлагаете в место LinearLayout? Я другие Layout попробовал но результата не получил :(

Comment: А в чем проблема вручную сделать перенос если не влазит? Там добавится пара несчатных if и цикл.

Comment: Проблемы начинаются с тем что ширина кнопки не известна на момент ее создание. Если же известно то все просто. 1) Создается базовый LinearLayout с ориентацией vertical. 2) Потом добавляете LinearLayout с ориентацией horizontal. 3) дальше вычисляете сколько кнопок влезит в строку добавляете их в него и преходим к пункту 2

Comment: Собственно я так и думал сделать. Но надеялся, что есть просто какой-то параметр в Layout который задает ограничения по количеству элементов в строке(Похоже это GridLayout). Спасибо всем.  Вариантов хватит для размышления

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее разумно в таком случае реализовать собственный класс контейнера, работающий по принципу известного на других платформах `FlowLayout` - если элемент не входит в текущюю строку он автоматически переносится на следующюю.

Вы можете воспользоваться готовым решением, например библиотека [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) или реализовать все самостоятельно. В качестве руководства к действию может послужить [этот пример](http://suvitruf.ru/2013/11/17/3396/).

Answer (score 0):

Если ограничение API14+ не пугает, попробуйте GridLayout
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: Через support доступен с API 7 - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html